# Linear Algebra - Dimension given matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

When H is the subspace of V (space of 3x3) and V consists of all matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

How is it possible to find the dimension of H?

Is there a way we can transform the A matrices?

Comment: Perform the matrix given matrix multiplication and set the resulting linear expressions in the variables $a,b,...,i$ equal to zero. You should then be able to find the dimension.

Comment: I guess you mean H satisfies the property, and write A as the column vectors:($\alpha_1$,$\alpha_2$,$\alpha_3$). The equation means that $\alpha_1=2\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ is arbitrary.

Comment: So the resulting would be a-2b, d-2e, g-2h all 3 set to 0.

Comment: A simpler way may be to ask what are initial degrees of freedom, and subtract the number of constraints.

Comment: Nine variables, three homogeneous linear equations....